Register to 2 conferences at almost the same time with the same talk abstract/paper
I don't know how to do to prevent being blacklisted from journals. I wanted to give a talk at an international conference (and not to publish this work as a conference paper). I did not know that it is unethical to apply the same talk abstract for two conferences at the same time (I did submit the corresponding paper for publication to just one journal).
The conference A wanted the participant to register via emailing to a professor who handles this conference. It is the form with details and abstract I would like to give. I sent this form by email as mentioned, and did not receive any acknowledgement or response from him for around 10 days. At almost the same time, I made a contact to the conference B to ask questions about registration. My advisor told me that it is uncommon to pay the fee before a review so I asked them about this.
Then, 10 days later, I made the follow-up contacts to both the conferences. Only, conference B answered me (within a day) and they told me to send abstract and some details to them to review before paying the fee if suitable. Then, I prepared and sent the documents (based on the same paper) to conference B and they accepted my talk. I did not know until recently that we shouldn't apply 2 conferences altogether. I did not receive any response from conference A so is this still a bad practice? How can I do now to prevent being blacklisted? I am so nervous.

‘I am so nervous.’ Start by stopping that.

Are you trying to publish your work as a conference paper in both? It's a bit hard to figure out what you think the issue is. If not, I don't see any harm at all. Plenty of people do back to back conferences.

No, I just want to give an oral presentation at one conference, and publish the paper in the journal. However, I sent to both of them the abstract of the talk without rejection from the conference A.

I read from this https://www.quora.com/Can-we-submit-research-paper-in-multiple-conferences-and-when-it-gets-accepted-in-one-we-later-withdraw-from-others @CameronWilliams that may be issues even though I don't publish in the conference.

If the conferences don't require publication in a conference proceedings, I don't see what the problem is.

Thank you, I am a little less nervous from your answer.

You haven’t written anything about a response from A, nor about paying any fees. Why do you think you actually are registered there? Do conferences in your field usually allow to cancel a registration? Most critically, why do you think "we shouldn't apply 2 conferences altogether" in the first place?


I don't receive any response from A until now, and I didn't pay any fee but just sent the abstract for consideration.
I don't know I am considered registered yet.
I don't know too.
Because I read from Quora's Barry answer and comments in the link above. @MisterMiyagi


Well, did you actually submit the same paper to both conferences, as the Quora Q&A discusses? Your question here doesn’t say you, only that you registered yourself to both, with the details of where you submitted the same work/abstract/paper missing. Please be aware that you can still [edit] your question, as it should contain all relevant details (so that people don’t have to pick them out of volatile comments).

@MisterMiyagi Thank you for reminding me. I edited the question. Please answer me about the question in this case.

The edit arguably makes this more confusing. A talk abstract and a conference paper are very different things. You're likely to get conflicting answers as a result. Pretty much every conference wants an abstract for the talk so that the organizers know what you're presenting about (to see if it's even relevant) and so attendees can see if your talk is worthwhile to them. There is no harm in applying to give a talk (without publication) to multiple conferences. A conference paper is for publication and you should not submit more than once as this is unethical for many reasons. Which is it here?

Thank you for your comment I got confused with the Quora comments. @CameronWilliams It is an abstract for the talk here.

@CameronWilliams While that may be true in your area, that is not true in all fields (OP hasn't named a field).

There are archival and non-archival conferences. (Extended) abstracts in the former count as publications, while presenting at a non-archival conferences is not immediately associated with a publication.
Submitting an (extended) abstract to an archival conference explicitly or implicitly includes promising that the material is not published or under review at any journal or other archival conference.
No such thing is applicable for submissions to non-archival conferences. One probably shouldn't talk about the same stuff too often, but there are no hard rules for this.
So in the situation described by the OP there only is a problem if both conferences are archival. Note that the status of conferences is highly correlated with the field. For example, CS conferences tend to by archival and math conferences tend to be not.

There is not such distinction in my field (I don't think we have archival conferences), and some conferences make you say "this work hasn't been presented on" and some don't. So you have to read the submission page for every conference you submit to.

Yes, my field is in math.
